# How to delete a bucket starting with a name using aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there any command of aws cli to delete all buckets starting with a specific name?

When I ran:

```
aws s3 ls
```

[image: list of buckets]

I got so many buckets, we need to frequently cleanup. If got any command, I can create a pipeline for it in gitlab and use that to cleanup.

Like you observe, I want to delete all the buckets starting with somename-

I tried using

```
aws s3 rb --force s3://somename-*
```

It didn't work.

Comment: `aws s3 rb` doesn't have a filter so you might want to parse the `s3 ls` and pass the selected buckets to `s3 rb`.

Comment: even s3 ls also not accepting *, could you please elaborate how to do that

Answer (score 3):

There's no built in way to accomplish this.  On Unix-like platforms, you can list all of the buckets and use some tools to filter the list and call in the CLI to remove all of the buckets that match some pattern:

```
aws s3api list-buckets --query 'Buckets[].[Name]' --output text | grep "^somename-" | xargs -n1 -IB echo aws s3 rb s3://B
```

Remove the "`echo` " after verifying the command will remove the buckets you want removed.

Comment: Hmm this command no longer works for me :)

Comment: +1, most people will probably hit this error: "An error occurred (BucketNotEmpty) when calling the DeleteBucket operation: The bucket you tried to delete is not empty"

Comment: Adding `--force` to the end of the command works as expected:
`aws s3api list-buckets --query 'Buckets[].[Name]' --output text | grep "^somename-" | xargs -n1 -IB aws s3 rb s3://B --force`